# TypeError: _this. is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I am getting a strange error when I try and call a service function from within the subscribe() method of another service function call. The TypeError states:

```
TypeError: _this.fileloaderService.downloadFile is not a function
```

I have two services, one to get some episodes, and another to load the contents of a file. I import them both and include them in my EpisodesComponent constructor like so:

```
import { EpisodeService } from '../episode.service';
import { FileloaderService } from '../fileloader.service';

constructor(private episodeService: EpisodeService,
  private fileloaderService: FileloaderService) { }
```

Then I get my episodes, and when they are returned I try to load a file from a url that is a field in my episode object:

```
getEpisodes(): void {
  this.episodeService.getEpisodes().subscribe(episodes => {
    this.episodes = episodes;
    for (let i of this.episodes) {
      this.fileloaderService.downloadFile(i.fileUrl).subscribe(file => {
        i['file'] = file;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

However, in the console when it is run it complains about the downloadFile() method not existing. However it compiles correctly and you can see it does exist 
in the service below.

```
@Injectable()
export class FileloaderService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  downloadFile(fileUrl): Observable<Text> {
    let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: ResponseContentType.Text});
    return this.http.get(fileUrl, options)
      .catch(this.handleError('downloadFile'));
  }
```

It seems like it is complaining it doesn't exist/isn't instantiated or something, but the way I've created and included the two services is identical.

Any ideas? (I'm completely new to Typescript so please go easy on me!) Thanks in advance...

**EDIT 1**: I am running this using ng serve --open
I have included:

```
console.log("fileloaderService:" + JSON.stringify(this.fileloaderService));
```

inside the getEpisodes().subscribe() function and it outputs this:

```
fileloaderService: {}
```

**EDIT 2**: I have also added the service to the app.module.ts providers like this:

```
providers: [EpisodeService, FileloaderService],
```

**EDIT 3**: I've created a stackblitz of the app simplified here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sazw43

Unfortunately I'm struggling to get the in-memory-web-api stuff to work correctly at the moment but you should be able to see everything as I have it (I think)

Comment: Your code seems fine, could you post it on stackblitz and give us the link ? I will take care of mocking the HTTP calls for you, and will try to find your issue.

Comment: what does console.log(this.fileloaderService) show? Also, is  FileloaderService a class or an interface? Did you try to run your app in development mode and/or production mode (ng build -prod) ?

Comment: When I log it to the console it gives: fileloaderService: [object Object]. When I JSON.stringify it, it gives: fileloaderService: {}

Comment: I am running the app with: ng server --open

Comment: The idea of making `console.log(this.fileloaderService)` in `getEpisodes` is good. Can you try that and post what the console shows, with its properties shown?

Comment: You did add your service to the providers, right?

Comment: I've added the stackblitz now, but having a little difficulty getting the in-memory-web-api working @trichetriche

Comment: The service was added to the providers, as i've show in edit 2 @David

Comment: I've added the output of the console.log of the service in Edit 1 @OscarPaz

Comment: How do you call getEpisodes? Is it a callback when you click a button or sth? Or is it called from code?

Comment: In the code you posted in stackblitz the error you report does not happen. But in your local machine, seems that `fileloaderService` is an empty object (`{ }`). It's strange...

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your issue ... Are you sure you are having it on the stackblitz ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6endd?file=app/episode/episode.component.ts

Comment: From the code - the getEpisodes is called from the ngInit() @sn42

Comment: @trichetriche You don't seem to be calling the getEpisodes function at all in your episode.component. I have it calling from the ngInit(), which you've removed?

Comment: You can add it back if you want, but you will have to remove the console log of your service. Otherwise, it will throw a circular object error. You can't stringify a whole class. But even if you correct this, your issue doesn't seem to be popping ...

Comment: could it possible be something to do with the in-memory-web-api that i am using causing something to go askew? That seems to be the main difference between the two @trichetriche

Comment: I would say no, but then again, I don't know your full code. Could you post your full stack trace, along with the lines that are causing the issue ? This would be the easiest way to find your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was caused by the http.get() in the downloadFile() method was not properly formatted and does not except a RequestOptions object like I was trying to use.

This was caused i think by using the deprecated @angular/http library with the newer @angular/common/http

Sorry for wasting everybodies time

Answer (score 0):

HI can you try like this

```
getEpisodes(): void {
  this.episodeService.getEpisodes().subscribe(episodes => {
    this.episodes = episodes;
    var self = this;
    for (let i of this.episodes) {
      self.fileloaderService.downloadFile(i.fileUrl).subscribe(file => {
        i['file'] = file;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: can you provide your pluker link